# Should this math question be migrated to Math Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

Should the following question be migrated to Math Stack Exchange:

[McCarthy’s Inequality for $\alpha > 1$](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122797/mccarthy-s-inequality-for-alpha-1)

Comment: While yes, this is a math question, this would actually be better suited if migrated to Math Overflow (since it appears to be more research level mathematics)